Chrome extension: How to show custom UI for a PDF file in Manifest V3?
This question has been already answered
Chrome extension: How to show custom UI for a PDF file?
However, the answer seems outdated as it uses manifest V2. How to achieve same in manifest V3 ?
I tried
rules.json

With
 [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "redirect",
      "redirect": {
        "transform": {
          "scheme": "chrome-extension",
          "host": "mbojebcnkfasdfalsdfkjalsdkjfa",
          "path": "/viewer.html",
          "queryTransform": {
            "addOrReplaceParams": [
              {
                "key": "file",
                "value": "{url}"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "condition": {
      "urlFilter": "*.pdf",
      "resourceTypes": ["main_frame", "sub_frame"]
    }
  }
]

And this,
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Selection Popup",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Shows a popup near text selection.",
  "permissions": [
    "scripting",
    "contextMenus",
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "declarativeNetRequest",
    "declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [
      {
        "id": "ruleset_1",
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "rules.json"
      }
    ]
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icons/icon16.png",
      "48": "icons/icon48.png",
      "128": "icons/icon128.png"
    }
  },
  "options_page": "popup.html",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ],
      "css": [
        "styles.css"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "popup.html",
        "script.js",
        "pdf.worker.min.js", "pdf.mjs"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  }
}

But when I open a local pdf file, nothing happens, it still uses the Chrome Default PDF viewer.
Goal is to achieve what this extension does:
https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm


To redirect a URL, it must be in the extension's host permissions. Since you want to process PDFs on all hosts, you need "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]

To redirect to your own page while preserving the original URL and avoid hardcoding the id of the extension you need updateDynamicRules (see this answer) in the background script:
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(e => {
  if (e.reason !== 'update' && e.reason !== 'install') return;
  const EXT_PAGE = chrome.runtime.getURL('/viewer.html');
  const ID = 1;
  chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
    removeRuleIds: [ID],
    addRules: [{
      id: ID,
      action: {
        type: 'redirect',
        redirect: {regexSubstitution: EXT_PAGE + '#\\0'},
      },
      condition: {
        regexFilter: /^.+\.pdf(\?.*)?$/.source,
        resourceTypes: ['main_frame', 'sub_frame'],
      },
    }],
  });
});

Now your extension page (viewer.html) can read this URL:
const origUrl = location.hash.slice(1);

As of Chrome 127, we can also match by content type in declarativeNetRequest, but it's not yet enabled in the stable version, so I'm not demonstrating it.

To redirect to a page in your extension, it must be listed in web_accessible_resources:
  "web_accessible_resources": [{
    "resources": ["viewer.html"],
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
  }],


A published extension from the web store can't open local files by default. The user must enable file access manually in the extension's details in chrome://extensions page.

Remove declarativeNetRequest from permissions because it unnecessarily adds a warning at installation and you already have declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess + host_permissions.

Remove declarative_net_request from manifest.json.

You probably don't need content_scripts running in all pages unconditionally.



Thanks the extra chrome extension best practice tips !

Hello @woxxom, sorry to bump into this again, but after testing, I get jgcnnoinoieleaplj is blockedThis page has been blocked by Chrome ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT when I tried to open a local pdf file. Then when I go the url bar and hit enter, it works. But when I open a cloud hosted pdf, I don't need to go through that manual step, it should loads the chrome extension immediately. Any idea why this happen ?

I got a new observation. If I drag and drop the local pdf in chrome, it does what I describe in my previous comment. However, if I drag and drop the local pdf in the url bar directly (or tab header), it works fine. Why could that happen ?

It's a bug in Chrome. You can probably use chrome.webNavigation.onErrorOccurred or chrome.tabs.onUpdated to detect these tabs and then redirect manually via chrome.tabs.update or chrome.tabs.reload.
